# Flatten object by specific keys in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

From the Google Maps API I get all route alternatives between two locations:

```
url = http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=rodovia-helio-smidt-s-n-cumbica-guarulhos+Brasil&destination=rua-coronel-diogo-814-jardim-da-gloria-sao-paulo+Brasil&alternatives=true&sensor=false
```

Now I want to find the shortest distance. So I have to loop through all routes, write each distance into a new array and then get the smallest value from this new array:

```
uri = URI(url)
response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
responseJson = JSON.parse(response)

routes = responseJson['routes'] 
distances = Array.new

routes.each do |route|
  distances.push(route['legs'][0]['distance']['value'])
end

shortest = distances.min
```

This works, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way using maybe &map or something like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
distances = responseJson['routes'].map { |r| r['legs'][0]['distance']['value'] }

shortest = distances.min
```

Or, if you like everything in one line:

```
shortest = responseJson['routes'].map { |r| r['legs'][0]['distance']['value'] }.min
```

The complete code will look like this:

```
uri = URI(url)
response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
responseJson = JSON.parse(response)

distances = responseJson['routes'].map { |r| r['legs'][0]['distance']['value'] }
shortest = distances.min
```